# How can I build multiple shop mannegement web(cms)?

Tags: android, wordpress, magento, e-commerce

I want to build cross platform software, where my customers will be shopkeepers and they will be able to manage their shop through that, how can i build this??
can I build this type website in wordpress,magento? Pls suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best if you do not use a specific e-commerce/WP framework to build on, but create an API that stores the information in your database. Then you can create plugins for different platforms (WP, Magento, etc.) to connect to the API and display the data accordingly. You are pretty much trying create Shopify/Bigcommerce as far as I can tell. Check out their API's to see how they work, this will be a good start.